# Any specific word for refferring and fetching back old data

Tags: verbs

I am looking for a specific word for referring and fetching some data from old document. e.g

```
"I pull out some points from my documents from last project."
```

I am trying to write something like above... I know "pull out" is really wrong choice of words. Any suggestions please.

Comment: I **retrieved** some points ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using those old  "points" specifically to support a new thesis (argument), the precise word is "adduce". Which is Latin for draw forth; or as you said, "pull out" (think of pulling arrows out of a quiver; ideas are your ammunition.)